# If statement getting hung up

Tags: php, regex, if-statement, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have a while loop that contains an if statement. The while loop works fine but when I run  the following if statement for each value passed through the while loop, and the if statement returns true, the script hangs up and I get the 30 second maximum execution time error.

I am not sure if it is creating an infinite loop or what. Can anyone spot the problem?

```
$size = count($_POST['itemname']);

// start a loop in order to update each record
$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
// define each variable
$itemname= $_POST['itemname'][$i];
$id = $_POST["id"][$i];


if(preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/',$itemname)) {

echo("has words");

} else {

//update code here



}
}
```

Comment: This could be much simpler with a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never increment `$i`, that is what is hanging it up as it will always be `< $size`

```
while ($i < $size) { // changed this to >
    // define each variable
    $itemname= $_POST['itemname'][$i];
    $id = $_POST["id"][$i];
    $i++; // increment $i
```

Answer (score 3):

You never increment `$i`. Try a for loop instead; they're a little more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

You need to increment $i somewhere outside of the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

you never change $i in the while loop

Answer (score 2):

you have to increment  $i for each loop or else if its true once it will always pass
add $i++ between the last 2 
}
}
so it looks 
}
$i++;
}